# How to change a line in my .html file which created and written in c?

Tags: html, c, file, line-breaks

I used this -> `fprintf(file, "\r\n");` but doesn't change line.

I have a webserver written in c. After the connection I create an html file with content like this:

```
This file was saved at :Fri Apr 19 00:49:43 2019 (line break!)
Please click here.
```

Code:

```
file = fopen("testvideo.html", "w");

if (file == NULL)
{
    /* File not created hence exit */
    printf("Unable to create file.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}


time(&tv);
timestr = ctime(&tv);
fprintf(file, "<html> The file was saved at:</html>");
fprintf(file, timestr);
fprintf(file, "\r\n");
fprintf(file,"<html> Please click :<a href=\"http://whatevevevever.com/testvideo.mp3\"\>HERE<a></html>");
fclose(file);
```

Comment: In HTML a line break is `<br>` not `\r\n`

Comment: but I want to do it in C?

Comment: But you are outputting *HTML*. Also, your HTML is *very* invalid.

Comment: Oh ok thanks. Why do I get the correct timestr in my HTML page since it's also in C?

Comment: You may want to read ["What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues here, one of which is definitely key:

1. In HTML a line break is `<br>` not `\r\n`
2. Your HTML isn't correct (or valid). I won't give an HTML tutorial here but you need to use the correct structure for your HTML to be sure browsers will render it correctly.

Corrected code:

```
if (file == NULL)
{
    /* File not created hence exit */
    printf("Unable to create file.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}


time(&tv);
timestr = ctime(&tv);
fprintf(file, "<html> <body>The file was saved at:");
fprintf(file, timestr);
fprintf(file, "<br>Please click :<a href=\"http://whatevevevever.com/testvideo.mp3\"\>HERE<a></body></html>");
fclose(file);
```